# Picture loses quality after implicite upload to ftp server

Tags: php, ftp

When I successfully upload picture to ftp server using PHP, it not only loses quality, but it's totally deformed.Enoguh speaking, here you go:

[image]

Why does this happen? When I upload pictures manually, everything works fine.

Comment: are you sure your code is connecting/uploading as binary to FTP?

Comment: Thanks :).Changed argument of ftp_put() from FTP_ASCII to FTP_BINARY and it works.